# Bulk rename files to remove all text before character

Tags: bash, batch-rename

I have a folder with many sub folders nested inside of with images with the name such as "IMG_7729-300x300.jpeg¦IMG_7729-300x300.jpeg". I am trying to find a way using linux to delete all text before the | and including it.

I tried using this but was unable to get it to work

```
find . -type f -name "*|*" -exec bash -c 'f="$1"; g="${f/*|/}"; mv -- "$f" "$g"' | '{}' \;
```

Comment: Use the `rename` command. It can do pattern-based renaming.

Comment: `¦` and `|` are two different characters.

Comment: I've done many answers with `rename`, see https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2836621%20rename

Comment: Be aware there are TWO different packages that provide `rename` on various Linux distributions. One from the `util-linux` package (no regex pattern reename) and `perl-rename` that provides a much more flexible implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Use bash [string manipulation](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) and a glob:

```
touch "IMG_7729-300x300.jpeg¦IMG_7729-300x300.jpeg"
echo "before:"
ls
for fn in *¦*; do
   mv "$fn" "${fn##*¦}"
done

echo "after:"
ls
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vyS/NDlDQcnT1z3e3NzIUtfYwKACiPWyClLTDy3DKqzElZqcka@glJSall@UaqXElVPMBWQppOUpZOYpaIHVWCuk5HMpKCjklikoqaTlKSmoVKflKStrHVpWy5WSn5fKBTUjMa0ktQhsxP//AA)

If you want to use `find` this is the best approach:

```
find . -type f -name "*¦*" -execdir bash -c 'fn="{}"; mv "$fn" "${fn##*¦}"' \;
```

With the `-execdir` primary, find executes the command in the directory where the file is found. You don't, therefor, need to deal with the qualifying path before the base filename.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to do it simply as well if you lack a POSIX shell (most are). With `awk` you can simply use `'¦'` as the field-separator `FS` and the system command to move the file to a name comprised of the second field only, e.g.

```bash
$ls -1 *.jpeg | awk -F¦ '{cmd="mv "$1FS$2" "$2; system(cmd)}' -
```

Where you simply pipe the output of `ls -1` (that's *"dash one"* not *"dash lowercase L"*). The `cmd` is just a string concatenation creating the string `mv $1¦$2.jpeg $2.jpeg`. (where `FS` is used for `'¦'`) The `system()` command simply passes that to the shell. You can adjust the file glob as desired to meet your needs if you have names ending in other than `.jpeg`, etc.

The result it it would take a directory containing:

```
$ ls -al
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 3 david david 4096 Jan  9 21:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 david david 4096 Nov 18 03:45 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 david david 4096 Jan  9 21:56 orig
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Jan  9 21:53 IMG_7721-300x300.jpeg¦IMG_7721-300x300.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Jan  9 21:53 IMG_7722-300x300.jpeg¦IMG_7722-300x300.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Jan  9 21:53 IMG_7723-300x300.jpeg¦IMG_7723-300x300.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Jan  9 21:53 IMG_7724-300x300.jpeg¦IMG_7724-300x300.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Jan  9 21:53 IMG_7725-300x300.jpeg¦IMG_7725-300x300.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Jan  9 21:53 IMG_7726-300x300.jpeg¦IMG_7726-300x300.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Jan  9 21:53 IMG_7727-300x300.jpeg¦IMG_7727-300x300.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Jan  9 21:53 IMG_7728-300x300.jpeg¦IMG_7728-300x300.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Jan  9 21:53 IMG_7729-300x300.jpeg¦IMG_7729-300x300.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  115 Oct 17  2021 f1
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  117 Oct 17  2021 f2
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  117 Oct 17  2021 f3
```

and move the filenames as desire resulting in the contents:

```
$ ls -al
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 3 david david 4096 Jan  9 22:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 david david 4096 Nov 18 03:45 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 david david 4096 Jan  9 21:56 orig
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Jan  9 21:53 IMG_7721-300x300.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Jan  9 21:53 IMG_7722-300x300.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Jan  9 21:53 IMG_7723-300x300.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Jan  9 21:53 IMG_7724-300x300.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Jan  9 21:53 IMG_7725-300x300.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Jan  9 21:53 IMG_7726-300x300.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Jan  9 21:53 IMG_7727-300x300.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Jan  9 21:53 IMG_7728-300x300.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Jan  9 21:53 IMG_7729-300x300.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  115 Oct 17  2021 f1
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  117 Oct 17  2021 f2
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  117 Oct 17  2021 f3
```

*Note:* if you do have bash or shell allowing redirection from a subshell, you can eliminate the pipe using `<(ls -1 *.jpeg)`, e.g.

```bash
awk -F¦ '{cmd="mv "$1FS$2" "$2; system(cmd)}' <(ls -1 *.jpeg)
```

(same result)

---

**Using perl-rename**

You can also use `perl-rename` (often symlinked to `rename` -- you can check which you have with `rename --version`). You will either see something like `"perl-rename 1.11"` or `"rename from util-linux 2.38.1"`)

With `perl-rename` you can use a simple substitute form `s/find/replace/` using extended-REGEX to accomplish the removal of the first part of the filename. In your case that would be:

```bash
$ perl-rename 's/^[^¦]+¦//' *.jpeg
```

Where the find is `^[^¦]+¦`:

- `'^'` anchored from the beginning of line
- `[^¦]+` select one-or-more characters not containing a `'¦'`
- then select the `'¦'`

And then replace with (nothing).

That will accomplish the same results as the `awk` command above. The same caveat applies, adjust the file-glob as needed to operate on the desired files. You can also use the `-n` option (`--just-print`, `--dry-run`) to see what would be renamed first without actually doing to rename to make sure you will accomplish your desired goal.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need, to rename a large number of files in order to remove a particular word from each filename. In my case I wanted to change the string "sidekiq_job" to just "job" for each file.

The solution I ended up finding most intuitive was a combination of `find`, a `for` loop, and `sed`:

```bash
for filename in $(find ./app/jobs -type f -name '*sidekiq_job.rb'); do
  mv "$filename" $(echo "$filename" | sed s/sidekiq_//g)
done
```

I've always found `awk`'s syntax a little hard to grok, so I like the ability to compose a few simple tools in this way.

Obviously you could use `sed` to replace the problematic string with whatever you want.

Hopefully someone finds that useful.